# Prove equality of set equations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have to prove that $$A\setminus(A\setminus B)=(B\setminus A)\triangle B$$
I am asked to do that by method, where:
we assume that some element $u\in A\setminus (A\setminus B) \Rightarrow u\in A\wedge u\notin(A\setminus B)   \Rightarrow ...$

In the end I have to manipulate this expression, so that in the end it would prove that $u\in((B\setminus A)\triangle B)$.

So my questions are:

1. I know that if $u\in(A\setminus B)$, then $u\in A \wedge u\notin B$,
   but whats the case with $u\notin(A \setminus B)$?
2. How is this technique called in English?
3. What would be the solution (step-by-step if possible) to this problem?

Comment: We have that $u \notin (A \setminus B)$ iff $u \in (A \setminus B)^c$. See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48201/complement-of-the-difference-of-the-sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set formula above is complicated; you have to find a "manageable" version of it.

First, "split" the problem into halfs, considering first the LHS and after the RHS.

The "trick" is to "play with" the set expressions (like : $A \cup B$) and their boolean "counterpart" (like : $u \in A \lor u \in B$), using the properties of the basic [set operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29).

*For the LHS*, you said :

> $u \in (A \setminus B)$ iff $u \in A ∧ u \notin B$, i.e. $u \in A ∧ u \in B^c$, i.e. $u \in A \cap B^c$.

We need the "equivalence" between $u \notin X$ and $u \in X^c$.

Thus :

> $u \in (A \setminus (A \setminus B))$ iff $u \in A ∧ u \notin (A \cap B^c)$, i.e. $u \in A ∧ u \in (A^c \cup B)$.

Now, we rewrite the last condition using *distributivity* :

$(u \in A \land u \in A^c) \lor (u \in A \land u \in B)$

which in turn is :

> $u \in (A \cap A^c) \lor u \in (A \cap B)$

which in turn is :

> $u \in \emptyset \lor u \in (A \cap B)$

which is :

> $u \in \emptyset \cup (A \cap B)$

and finally :

> > $u \in A \cap B$.

---

*For the RHS* we start with the definition of $\triangle $ :

> $A \triangle B$ is $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$.

Thus :

$(B\setminus A) \triangle B$ will be : $((B\setminus A) \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus (B\setminus A))$.

But we have already "solved" $(A \setminus (A \setminus B))$, which is : $A \cap B$; thus, "switching $A$ and $B$, we have that $(B \setminus (B\setminus A))$ is $B \cap A$, i.e. $A \cap B$.

Now we have "reduced" our problem to :

> $((B\setminus A) \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$.

How can we simplify $((B\setminus A) \setminus B)$ ?

If we use the steps used above for the LHS, we have that :

$((B\setminus A) \setminus B)$ is $(B\setminus A) \cap B^c$, i.e.$(B \cap A^c) \cap B^c$.

But *intersection* is commutative and associative; thus we have that :

> $((B\setminus A) \setminus B)$ is : $A^c \cap (B \cap B^c)$, i.e. $A^c \cap \emptyset$, i.e.$\emptyset$.

Finally, putting all together, we have that :

> > $(B\setminus A) \triangle B$ is $\emptyset \cup (A \cap B)$, i.e.$A \cap B$.

---

In conclusion, having proved that both the LHS and the RHS "simplify" to : $A \cap B$, we have proved that :

> > > $(A \setminus (A \setminus B)) = (B\setminus A) \triangle B$.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.